# Copy local = false not working for xap

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to set copy local to a project file of mine and it is still included in the xap even though it is set to false.  What might cause this to happen?

Comment: Out of interest, is it a project reference or DLL reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting copylocal to the class library does not work.  Add the dll to the application (even though it is not needed there) and set copy local to false and it will not add it to the xap.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a .dll file in your project you do not want to have in the XAP, then you must set this in your reference of the project not on the file itself.
You gave so little info about your problem it's hard to guess what is really going on with your project. Next time give a little more effort to elaborate the problem.